# DB2 Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table

Tags: sql, db2

when I am executing a mass load copy I got an error like
*[Code: -668, SQL State: 57016]  Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table "MASS_TABLE".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, DRIVER=4.28.11*

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MASS_LOAD
    ()
   LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC SQL220916104128256
    BEGIN
    call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(
    'LOAD FROM (SELECT 5, NAME, TYPE FROM MASS_TABLE WHERE ID = 3) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO MASS_TABLE'
    );
    END
```

What I observed afterwards I cannot make a *Select* on the table, until I execute

```
SET INTEGRITY FOR MASS_TABLE CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, MATERIALIZED QUERY, STAGING, GENERATED COLUMN IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED;
```

How can I handle it inside the stored procedure?

Comment: The documentation explains it very well:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=integrity-checking-violations . You can dynamically query the table status (in your stored procedure) following the load and conditionally run the `set integrity ...` (which is SQL, not a command).

Comment: Do you have a quick example of usage with dynamic query on the table status?

Comment: Coding varies with the nature of your database, i.e. if you have declarative RI in addition to other column check constraints etc. You may need to include other tables in the `set integrity` or run the `set integrity` on the tables in the correct order.  To find tables in check-pending, `syscat.tables.type='T' and syscat.tables.status='C'`. If you have MQTs they may also need to be processed. I cannot share confidential code, but this stuff is trivial.

Comment: Ok I just got it, but I figured out that select and copy in the same table is not working, maybe I need a temporary table in my sp.  

`declare C1 cursor for select 'AA', Name, Date from MASS_TABLE ;

call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(
'load from '' || C1 || '' of cursor insert into MASS_TABLE  nonrecoverable'
);`

`[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "cursor" was found following "OF".  Expected tokens may include:  "ASC".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11`

Comment: There is no such syntax for the `CURSOR` type in [LOAD command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load-using-admin-cmd).

Answer (score 0):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

CREATE TABLE MASS_TABLE AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
    VALUES 
      (3, 'NAME1', 'TYPE1')
    , (3, 'NAME2', 'TYPE2')
  ) T (ID, NAME, TYPE)
) WITH DATA@

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.T AS (SELECT * FROM MASS_TABLE WHERE ID = 3) '
  ||'WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED';
  CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD FROM (SELECT 5, NAME, TYPE FROM SESSION.T) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO MASS_TABLE (ID, NAME, TYPE) NONRECOVERABLE');
END@

SELECT * FROM MASS_TABLE@
```

| ID | NAME | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NAME1 | TYPE1 |
| 3 | NAME2 | TYPE2 |
| 5 | NAME1 | TYPE1 |
| 5 | NAME2 | TYPE2 |

Comment: Thx for the detailed description and sorry for the question, but how can I can call such like a script in my db2 client?

Comment: Sure, you can. Just tun 2 distinct statements in the same connection sequentially: DECLARE and CALL. These are ordinal SQL statements. I combined them into a single compound statement just to show how to use them in a routine. Just in case: you may even use the same compound statement with your client as well if you know how to do this.

Comment: I just now tested, with your code it works. But when I am executing it on my table I got an error  
`[Code: -668, SQL State: 57007]  Operation not allowed for reason code "1" on table "MyCustomTable".. SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007, DRIVER=4.28.11`

I also added following in addition to your code, 
`'SET INEGRITY FOR MyCustomTable Check Immediate Unchecked';`

Comment: Just in case. You should be aware of `UNCHECKED` use consequences. Use it, if your are sure that you load valid data only, because you may easily violate, say, referential integrity rules with it. Use `IMMEDIATE CHECKED` to make Db2 check data integrity otherwise.

Comment: Sure, but how can I avoid this error  `Operation not allowed for reason code "1"`, because no data will be copied when this error ocuurs.

Comment: LOAD is low level command, which doesn't check many types of table constraints if they exist. The solution is to delete them to avoid placing the table into this state.

Comment: Will be no any other solution without deletion of this constraint to copy the data?

Comment: Sure. Use INSERT statement, for example, instead.

Comment: But in case of insert all insert and update triggers will be triggered, thats why I want to prefer this way.

Comment: Code your triggers to fire conditionally using, say, some flag in a service table. You may even disable triggers in your own session only using a global variable and coding your triggers to check its value.

Comment: Hmm is it possible to say that the triggers should only be deactivated in my session using global variable? 
This means, suppose anyone is calling the stored procedure. The stored procedure is starting copy process by deactivating the triggers via global variable. At the same time another process want to make inserts. So for this process the triggers should be active. So how can I tell that it should be only deactivated by the one session?

Comment: Please, ask another disttinct question on this like how to code triggers to fire depending on some condition. It helps to avoid very lengthy discussion in comments to answer to absolutely different question. Specify if you need to "disable"  (it's not disabling actually, but rather conditional firing) triggers for all seasons or just for the current one. Me or someone else could describe how to do this with some practical example.